# Does adding a capacitor with a transformer makes it a LC filter?

Tags: capacitor, transformer, filter

when i add a capacitor with a transformer is a LC filter formed? Moreover if it acts as a LC filter then what inductance to be considered for checking the frequency response of this filter, whether i should consider the leakage inductance of the transformer or the inductance of the coils?

Answer (score 1):

A transformer is "just" two (or more) windings that are constructed in a way that they are coupled via induction, that is they are inductors.

As such you can arrange a capacitor with one of the windings in an LC configuration, and it will be an LC filter.

For a good approximation of its behaviour (e.g. to input into a simulation), considering the coil inductance is usually good enough.

Answer (score 0):

If the transformer has no connection to the unused winding then the connected winding inductance is the Lthat resonates with the C added. This is usually a good approximation.

If the other winding is shorted then it is only the leakage inductance that counts toward resonance.

If the unused winding is open circuit and a significant number of turns, its self capacitance can affect things significantly so a realistic answer is that it depends on the actual transformer, the C added and the frequency desired for resonance.